# join won't work after replacing a character in list

Tags: python, string, list

```
import random

test1="test1"
test2="test2"
test3="test3"
test4="test4"

def choose():
    test=list("test ")
    number=random.randint(1, 100)
    test[-1]=number
    return test

var=choose()
print("".join(var))
```

This works fine with just `print(var)` but when I try to `join` it, it gives me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only `join` a list of strings. You could make your code work by doing the following.

```
import random

def choose():
    test=list("test ")
    number=random.randint(1, 100)
    test[-1]=str(number)
    return test

var=choose()
print("".join(var))
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because, you are assigning an int to `test[-1]` which can't be joined. Look at the error message:

> TypeError: sequence item 4: expected string, int found

Try:

```
test[-1]=str(number)
```

Try to read and analyze the error message. It is given, so that you can find the cause of error.